# Python - a custom range where after add +1 to max then return minimum

Tags: python

I wonder if there is any function in python like that.

**Example 01:**
For example, if I specify the **range from (1,12)** integer. Then:

- if current value is 12 and I add 1, it return 1 (go back to minimum)
- if current value is 11 and I add 3, it return 2

**Example 02:**
Another example is if I set **range from (5, 9)**. Then:

- If current value is 8 and I add 2, it return 5
- If current value is 8 and I add 7, it return 5

I know I can write a self-defined function for that, I am just curious to know if python has that similar function built in

The self-defined function:

```
def wrap_range(val, nmin, nmax, add_val):
    nrange = nmax - nmin + 1
    remain = add_val % nrange
    val = val + remain
    if val <= nmax:
        return val
    else:
        val = val - nmax + nmin - 1
        return val
```

Comment: > If current value is 8 and I add 2, it return 5, then it should return 0?

Comment: no, the 2nd example range is (5-9). So if current value is 8. So when 8+2 = 8+1+1= 9+1 = return back to minimum of 5

Comment: TBH, I lost you, let me get a cup of coffee.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `remain = add_val % nrange` is not there in words yeah? Or am I missing something.

Comment: that is for the case if you add more than a range. I use example 2, when 8 + 7, the 7 is more than the range from 5 to 9. So it is literally equivalent to 8 + 2

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and say you have to make do with the function you wrote. Can't think of anything in-build if not in NumPy for something like this.

Comment: It's ok. Thank you so much. Just my curiosity if there is one

Comment: So the mathematical operations would be something like: `expected_value = ranges_min + value%(ranges_max - ranges_min)`? Or something close?

Comment: Yeah I thought same, but if it increases beyond max, then `val = val - nmax + nmin - 1` is done. @PTQuoc can probably correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score -1):

[Itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) has the `cycle` and `islice` functions that you can use to get what you want -

```py
from itertools import cycle, islice
def repeated_offset(nmin, nmax, start, n):
    rng = range(nmin, nmax + 1)
    start_idx = list(rng).index(start)
    value, *_ = islice(cycle(rng), start_idx + n, start_idx + n + 1)
    return value
```

```py
repeated_offset(1, 12, 12, 1)
# 1
repeated_offset(1, 12, 11, 3)
# 2
repeated_offset(5, 9, 8, 2)
# 5
repeated_offset(5, 9, 8, 7)
# 5
```

Answer (score -1):

What about looping, subtracting while the total value is bigger than the lower boundary, while subtracting range wide.

```
def loopit(val, the_min, the_max, addition):
    total = val + addition
    diff = the_max - the_min + 1
    if not total > the_min:
        raise ValueError("The total value must be larger then lowest boundary of the range")
    while the_max < total:
        total -= diff

    return total


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(loopit(12, 1, 12, 1))
    print(loopit(11, 1, 12, 3))
    print(loopit(8, 5, 9, 2))
    print(loopit(8, 5, 9, 7))
```

output:

```
1
2
5
5
```